# How do I put $g(x,y)$ into the second integration in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\mathop{\mathrm dy})\mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, indefinite-integrals

We have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\mathop{\mathrm dy}\right)\mathrm dx $$

What I would like to have is to put $g(x,y)$ into the second integral, so that it is easier to compute, when I am not able to calculate the integral from f itself.

If it is not possible, then maybe some of you know what I might do in this particular case, when $g(x,t)=e^{tx}$ and $f(x,t)=e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}e^{-itx}$, if one is interested this is a function generating moments for Alpha stable distributions.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: yes, but i thought Fubini is for g(x,y)=1?

Comment: There is a problem with your set-up.  You have $y$ appearing twice.  Once as the variable of integration and the other outside the integral.  What is the relationship between them?

Comment: right, sorry they both different y, so this question makes no sense

Comment: Since they're different $y$'s if you change one to a different letter and everything is integrable, then Fubini's theorem will allow you to combine the integrals.  (It's more general than equaling $1$.)